# Error expresion regular dentro de un if en bash

Tags: bash

Tengo este script en la cual te pide un dni en un variable:

```
#!bin/bash

pr="^[0-9]{8}[[:upper:]]$"

read dni

if [ $dni =~ $pr ];then

echo bien

else 

echo mal

fi
```

Y pongo un dni valido y me da este error:

```
12345678A

21.sh: línea 4: [: =~: se esperaba un operador binario

mal
```

No conozco ese error a ver si alguien puede ayudarme,Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El script tiene varios errores.
La variable pr es una expresión regular. No lleva las comillas.
El término if los corchetes

```
#!bin/bash
pr=^[0-9]{8}[[:upper:]]
if [[ $dni =~ $pr ]]; then
    echo bien
else 
    echo mal
fi
```

Comment: Gracias me sirvio.